# Please criticize my attempted proof of a simple set theory lemma.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am reading Terrence Tao's analysis 1 and am new to writing proofs. I'm currently financially unstable and have no one to talk about math's with, so any criticm would help me so much.

---

In his book, I was asked to prove the following statement:

Let X, Y be sets. 
Define a partial function from X to Y to
be 
any function f : X' → Y' whose domain X' is a subset of X, 
and whose
range Y' is a subset of Y.

Show that the collection of all partial functions
from X to Y is itself a set.

(Hint: use Exercise 3.4.6, the power set axiom, the
replacement axiom, and the union axiom.)

---

All of the ZFC axioms of set theory except the axiom of choice are allowed to be assumed to prove this statement.

A set is considered by terrence tao at that stage of the book, and collection of mathematical object that satisfies all of the set theory axioms except the axiom of choice.

(Power set axiom). Let X and Y be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted Y X, which consists of all the functions from X to Y, thus
f ∈ Y X ⇐⇒ (f is a function with domain X and range Y).

Axiom 3.11 (Union). Let A be a set, all of whose elements are themselves sets. Then there exists a set UA whose elements are precisely
those objects which are elements of the elements of A, thus for all objects x
x ∈ UA ⇐⇒ (x ∈ S for some S ∈ A).

(Replacement). Let A be a set. For any object x ∈ A, and
any object y, suppose we have a statement P(x, y) pertaining to x and
y, such that for each x ∈ A there is at most one y for which P(x, y) is
true. Then there exists a set {y : P(x, y) is true for some x ∈ A}, such that for any object z, z ∈{y : P(x, y) is true for some x ∈ A}
⇐⇒ P(x, z) is true for some x ∈ A.

Ex 3.4.6 :
Lemma 3.4.9:
Let X be a set. Then the set
{Y : Y is a subset of X}
is a set.
Proof. See Exercise 3.4.6.

My attempted proof:

Let X and Y be sets.

{A | A is a subset of X} is a set by lemma 3.4.10,  
let P(X) = {A | A is a subset of X}

{A | A is a subset of Y} is a set by lemma 3.4.10, 
let P(Y) = {A | A is a subset of Y}

Let y be any subset of Y, i.e let y ∈ P (Y).

For each x ∈ P (X), there exists a unique set denoted by yx , 
which consists of all functions 
f, f:x -> y.

Also, for any object z, let P(x,z) be the property 
pertaining to x and z := “ z = yx ”.

By the replacement axiom, we have that 
{z | z = yx for any x ∈ P (X)} is a set, 
for each subset y of Y.

For each y ∈ P (Y), 
there exists one set {z | z = yx for any x ∈ P (X)} 
as previously established.

Also, for any object z, 
let P(y,z) be the property 
pertaining to y and z := “ z = {z | z = yx for any x ∈ P (X)}”.

By the replacement axiom, we have that 
{z | z = {z | z = yx for any x ∈ P (X)} 
for each subset y of Y} is a set.

Let A = {z | z = {z | z = yx for any x ∈ P (X)} for each subset y of Y}.

By the axiom of union, we have ⋃ A is a set, 
such that x ∈ ⋃ A ⇐⇒ (x ∈ S for some S ∈ A), 
which is equivalent to  
x ∈ ⋃ A ⇐⇒ x is some function from a subset of X to a subset of Y.

Any help is appreciated.Also if you want to rewrite it to be proper that would help me learn also. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The re-use of letters is quite confusing, I think your $P$ needs to be accompanied by $Q$ so that you write $P(X)$ and $Q(Y)$, and similarly for other similar re-uses...

Comment: Ask yourself which posting is easier for a reviewer to read, your original posting, or my edited version.  Section dividers are done via `-----`, while line breaks are done via `<br>`.  Going forward, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which is straightforward to learn, to express your math on this forum.

Comment: @user2661923 your editing is wonderful, thank you :)

Comment: @abiessu thank you for tip, I think I will try to fix it

Comment: "Show that the collection of all partial functions from X to Y is itself a set" : This is the specific conjecture that you are attempting to prove.  Consider your presentation from the perspective of the reader.  The first question that the reader who is unfamiliar with the class definitions will ask is : *What is a set ?*  I am guessing that the definition is something like: a set is any finite or infinite collection of elements.  Assuming so, I would present this definition up front.  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, considering the *hint* : "use Exercise 3.4.6, the power set axiom, the replacement axiom, and the union axiom", at a minimum, I would also state the results of the exercise and the axioms up front.  This way, the reader would have an immediate idea of what premises may be assumed to be true.

Comment: @user2661923 ok I have updated it with your recommendations :)

Comment: Your editing looks pretty good.  Personally, I am unfamiliar with this topic, so I have no opinion on your proof's validity.

Comment: This proof looks fine to me! Nice work. It is *very* detailed - I generally think that this level of detail is a bit overkill but that's a matter of difference of taste between Tao and myself :). I agree that MathJax would help with clarity though - I'm guessing you mean to denote the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ as $Y^X$. I have to say I disagree with abiessu's suggestion that you denote the powerset of $Y$ by $Q(Y)$, but you should indeed avoid re-using the letter $P$. You could either use $2^X$ or $\mathcal P$ for powerset, or use $\phi$ for properties for example.